# Programación de calculo subtotal en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Soy nuevo por aquí. Tengo un problema con un cálculo de un subtotal.
No puedo cambiar el formato del formulario (trabajo de clase). Se elige una opción del select con un precio fijo y según el plazo en meses se resta un 5% cuanto mayor sea el plazo (Plazo en meses
    
), aparte se suma 400 por cada checkbox marcado. El código .js es el siguiente:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#plazo").change(function(){
                var option = $("#option1", "#option2", "#option3").val(){
                    return value;
                }
                var recargo = $("#plazo").val(){
                    if (("#plazo").value == '1'){
                        var option.val - (var option.val() * 5) / 100;
                    }
                    return value;
                }
                var extras = $('.checkbox:checked') = 400{
                    return value;
                }
            })
        
            var subtotal = option - recargo + extras{
                return value;
            }
            document.getElementById("#presupuesto").text = subtotal;    
        })
```

```html
<html>
        <body>
        <form name="formulario" method="post" id="form2" action="#">
        <h5>Tipo de página web</h5>
        <select name="typeof" id="myselect" placeholder="Tipo de página web">
         <option id="option1" value="1000"> 1 Web estática</option>
         <option id="option2" value="2000">2 Web dinámica</option>
         <option id="option3" value="3000">3 Web dinámica + tienda online</option>
        Tipo de página web:
        </select><br>
        <h5>Plazo en meses</h5>
        <input type="text" name="plazo" class="textbox" maxlength="9" size="40" id="plazo" value="" placeholder="Plazo en meses" /><br>
        <h5>Marque las secciones deseadas:</h5><br><br>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="who" class="checkbox2" value="">Quienes somos</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="where" class="checkbox2" value="">Donde estamos</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="photo" class="checkbox2" value="">Galería de fotos</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="commerce" class="checkbox2" value="">eCommerce</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="manage" class="checkbox2" value="">Gestión interna</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="news" class="checkbox2" value="">Noticias</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="face" class="checkbox2" value="">Facebook</div>
        <div class="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="twit" class="checkbox2" value="">Twitter</div>
        <h5>Presupuesto estimado</h5>
        <input type="text" name="estimado" class="textbox" maxlength="40" size="40" id="presupuesto" value=""/><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Cuando lo pruebo la consola me dice el siguiente error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { en la linea  var option =
>   $("#option1", "#option2", "#option3").val(){ ;

y me detiene la ejecución del script, por lo que no sé si sería la mejor forma de realizar la operación.

Necesito ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo es la asignación de variables, el error que te da es porque el formato de JQuery es:

`var tuOpcion = $("#idElemento").val();`

Parece que te has complicado intentando simplificar. Recuerda también el cerrar todos los elementos con `;`

Lo que intentas hacer con:

```
var recargo = $("#plazo").val(){
                if (("#plazo").value == '1'){
                    var option.val - (var option.val() * 5) / 100; 
                    //esto saltará ya que declaras una variable llamada option.val
                }
                return value;
            }
```

Es otro error, por lo anterior dicho y porque la estructuración mas adecuada seria el asignar el resultado de una función a una variable:

```
var recargo = ObtenerRecargo();

function ObtenerRecargo(){
    //En tu código no has añadido el $ y has cambiado value de javascript en vez de .val() de jquery
    var plazo = $("#plazo").val(); 
    //obtienes el valor de la opción seleccionada
    var opcion = $("#myselect").val();
    var resultado = "";

    if(plazo == '1'){
        resultado = opcion - ((opcion * 5)/100);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Te recomiendo que te replantees tu lógica, hay veces que es mejor volver a empezar, ya que si te doy una solución completa no aprenderías de tus errores.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, seguiré intentándolo, saludos

Comment: De nada, si te surgen mas dudas puedes acudir al sitio a formular otra pregunta,  también, si consideras que es correcta, te animo a que des al check para validar la respuesta, en caso de que no fuese lo que andabas buscando, comentamelo y gustosamente editare la pregunta